# Replace character with unknown type of case (lower or upper)

Tags: php

I want remove a specific character from a string, but the one i willing to remove is not stable, he can have lower or upper case in different position at each time.

***Let's make an example to understand what i mean:***

`$string1` can be like this:

```
$string1 = "Just a Big TeSt tO shoW";
```

Or any other possibility like:

```
$string1 = "JUST a BiG TEst To ShOw";
```

And the characters i want remove:

```
$string2 = "just a big test";
```

The result must be: "To Show" or "tO shoW" ... depend on `$string1` (lower and upper case here are important).

**What i did ?**

```
$result = str_replace($string2, "", $string1);
```

But nothing !

Comment: If only there was a case insensitive alternative, something like [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php).

Comment: @SmartyCoder i love you, many thank's !!!